# Can I replace rua entry with ruf in DMARC record?

Tags: email, security, spf, dkim, dmarc

I currently have a DMARC record set up like this:
`v=DMARC1; p=none; fo=1; rua=mailto:hello@example.com` but I am receiving a lot of reports everyday.

I would like to only receive failure reports (forensic reports) when either DKIM or SPF failed. So, can I replace the rua entry with ruf so that my record would look like this:
`v=DMARC1; p=none; fo=1; ruf=mailto:hello@example.com` or would this be treated as invalid?

I also tried this [DMARC record wizard](https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-record-wizard/) only with the ruf entry. It showed me this warning message:
`Warning! DMARC record has no rua tag so you cannot receive DMARC reports.`

Answer (score 1):

[The `ruf` directive is generally unsupported by email providers](https://serverfault.com/a/951075), so you will likely miss a lot of reports if you don't include an `rua` directive.

In other words, regardless of whether it's valid syntax to include only `ruf` (my hunch is that it *is* valid), that kind of setup won't give you the result you're looking for.

You will likely want to sign up for a DMARC monitoring service, which will supply you with a special email address for `rua` reports so that they can process them and show you a summary over time in a chart/table view. Using the service, you will be able to filter the data and pay special attention to the failures.

Comment: I am looking at Valimail for Office 365 as we are currently using O365 as our email provider. Seems like this is a free service. I think that might work and I can replace our organisation email with the special email address provided by Valimail. Is this how this thing works?

Comment: @user1448031 I believe that is how it works, yes.